# Multiple hidden fields overwriting each other

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, hidden-field

I am creating a dashboard, on this dashboard I have multiple instantiations of the same web user control.

Each web user control contains its own hidden fields. These hidden fields overwrite each other which causes it to always return the last set value for all the instantiated web user controls.

Is there anyway I can get around this?

[Edit:]
This is what is supposed to happen:

[image]

Comment: could you give us an example? could you consider using data-* as "hidden" fields or you wahtn separate input in order to make the model binding work? can we see the data model that you want to receive?

Comment: Too much theory. The first i wonder is why the webuser-controls can overwrite each other at all.

Comment: Presumably you're setting the same ID (or name attribute) on a given hidden field for every user control it appears in.

Comment: I added an image to help explain what I'm trying to get. The web user controls do not overwrite each other, only their hidden fields. The hidden fields are given an ID as well

Answer (score -1):

I advice you to use that kind of data modeling in order to use one hidden field for each usercontrol:

```
public class MainModel
{
    public List<UserControl> {get;set;}
    public string otherfield {get;set;}
}

public class UserControl
{
    public string showableField {get;set;}
    public int hiddenfield {get;set;}
}
```

See more for model binding in [scott hanselman wensite](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)